# Creating napi_value from node.js native addon worker pool thread

Tags: c++, node.js, node-addon-api, n-api

Is it possible to create **napi_value** from a node.js (native) **worker thread** and share the value with the main thread.

For example:

```
napi_create_async_work( env, NULL, resource_name, Execute,  OnComplete,
                                       DataEx, &DataEx->work);
napi_queue_async_work(env, DataEx->work);
```

then construct a **napi_value** from the **"Execute()"** function (which will be getting executed by a worker pool thread).
eg:

```
void Execute(napi_env env, void *data)
{
  --   --   --
  napi_value val;    
  napi_create_int32( env, 101, &val);
  --   --  --
}
```